# Python - Does string contain all characters in another string?

Tags: python, string

I need to check if a string contains a set of characters, and they need to appear the correct number of times.

```
string1 = "somestring"
string2 = "thestrings"
characters = "egimnorsst" # Note that there are two 's' characters here
does_string_contain(string1, characters) # True
does_string_contain(string2, characters) # False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just sort and compare them.

```
>>> sorted("egimnorsst") == sorted("somestring")
True
```

Comment: @JuanTheron +1 comments are frowned upon... that's what the upvote button is for :)

Comment: lol, ok whateva.... sorry then

Answer (score 2):

One way is `collections.Counter`.

This method has a complexity of O(*n*) versus O(*n* log *n*) for `sorted`.

```
from collections import Counter

string1 = "somestring"
string2 = "egimnorsst"

Counter(string1) == Counter(string2)  # True
```

For large strings, this method is more efficient than sorted:

```
from collections import Counter
import random, string

def random_string(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for m in range(length))

n = 50000
string1 = random_string(n)
string2 = ''.join(random.sample(string1, n))

%timeit Counter(string1) == Counter(string2)  # 11.3 ms
%timeit sorted(string1) == sorted(string2)    # 41.6 ms
```

Comment: Would this run faster than sorting each string?

Comment: For larger strings, yes.